# No matching function for call to unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting an error which I don't understand. I'm sure it is quite simple.. but I am still learning C++.
I'm not sure if it is related to my parameters being exactly the same for the pure virtual function declaration or if it is something else.

Here is my simplified code:

```
in header_A.h

class HandlerType
{
public:
   virtual void Rxmsg(same parameters) = 0; //pure virtual
};

--------------------------------------------------
in header_B.h

class mine : public HandlerType
{
public:
   virtual void myinit();
   void Rxmsg(same parameters); // here I have the same parameter list 
//except I have to fully qualify the types since I'm not in the same namespace
};

--------------------------------------------------
in header_C.h

class localnode
{
public:
virtual bool RegisterHandler(int n, HandlerType & handler);
};
--------------------------------------------------

in B.cpp

using mine;

void mine::myinit()
{
   RegisterHandler(123, Rxmsg); //this is where I am getting the error
}

void Rxmsg(same parameters)
{
   do something;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `Rxmsg` can be used where a `HandlerType&` is expected?

Comment: What is HandlerType ?

Comment: `localnode::RegisterHandler(123,` Rxmsg); can call  without object in  mine class ?

Comment: @Jagannath, `HandlerType` is a class defined in the first header file.

Comment: You cannot use `Rxmsg` like that. Use `&ClassName::MemberName`. But it looks like you need an object, not a member here. Also, if you are asking about a compiler error, post the error text as is in its entirety, not your adaptation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that `bool RegisterHandler(int n, HandlerType & handler)` takes a reference to an object of the class `HandlerType` and you're trying to pass a function. Obviously that doesn't work.

So I think what you wanna do is passing `*this` instead of `Rxmsg`. This will supply `RegisterHandler` with an instance of the class `mine`, on which the overridden function `Rxmsg` can now be invoked.

Notice that the Function `Rxmsg` will, if done that way, be called on the exact same Object that the variable `*this` had, at the moment you supplied it to `RegisterHandler`.

I hope this is what you intended to do and I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `RegisterHandler(123, Rxmsg);` to `RegisterHandler(123, *this);` Solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Your feedback would be in a comment for the above answer rather than adding one more answer to your own question. Please upvote and accept the above answer..